# In VF, which fields can be accessed from $User?

Tags: visualforce

The [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_user.htm) say "User merge fields can reference information about the user such as alias, title, and ID." User has a ton of fields, and I'm looking for away to determine which fields are actually available through the $User global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The referenceable fields are the same as available to Formula fields and Validation Rules.

e.g. `$User.isactive`, `$User.email`, etc.  Consult the list by going to any Formula field or Validation Rule

[image]